# ValueErro:x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a scatter plot
It works perfectly fine until I add the condition where I want percent above 25%

It works if I use

```
try: pd_a = setting_df['PERCENT'].values
    except: pd_a = None
```

but when I changed the code as below I get error message saying **x and y must be the same size**
Can someone please advise me what causes the error?
I understand the error message pop up because x and y is not the same length but I am not sure how to correct it.

```
try: pd_a = setting_df['PERCENT'].values if setting_df['PERCENT'].values >= 25 else None
    except: pd_a = None
```

Here is the detailed code I've got.

```
 def scaling(y, convert_axis, origin_axis):
        var1 = (y - origin_axis[0]) * (convert_axis[1] - convert_axis[0])
        var2 = (origin_axis[1] - origin_axis[0])
        var3 = convert_axis[0]
        var = (var1/var2) + var3
        return var
        
    def setting_data(setting_df, _oil):
        try: pd_a = setting_df['PERCENT'].values if setting_df['PERCENT'].values >= 25 else None
        except: pd_a = None
        try: pd_b = setting_df['RPM'].values
        except: pd_b = None
        try: pd_c = setting_df['pressure'].values
        except: pd_c = None
        try: pd_d = setting_df['temeperature'].values
        except: pd_d = None
        try: pd_e = setting_df['Engine Inlet Temp'].values
        except: pd_e = None
           
         sensor_dic = {
                'load': pd_a,
                'rpm': pd_b,
                'Max': pd_c,
                'Comp': pd_d,
                'Scav': pd_e
                }
            return sensor_dic
        
            
if sensor_dic['rpm'] is not None:
   ax1.scatter(x=sensor_dic['load'],
               y=scaling(sensor_dic['rpm'], [ax_engspd[0], ax_engspd[-1]], range_list[0]),                              s=15, c='#8B4513')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only plot data where the `PERCENT` column has values >= 25 you can make a mask `m` and then select data according to the mask with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
def setting_data(setting_df, _oil):
    m = setting_df['PERCENT'] >= 25
    try: pd_a = setting_df.loc[m, 'PERCENT']
    except: pd_a = None
    try: pd_b = setting_df.loc[m, 'RPM'].values
    except: pd_b = None
    # etc.
```